# external storage: world-readable AND private?

Tags: android, local-storage, storage

I am confused regarding `android` external `storage`: it is world-readable but at the same time it is possible to save app-private files on it? isn't that a conflict?

> This page introduces the different data storage options available on Android:
>   1 - Internal file storage: Store app-private files on the device file system.
>   2 - External file storage: Store files on the shared external file system. This is usually for shared user files, such as photos.
>   3 - Shared preferences: Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
>   4 - Databases: Store structured data in a private database.
>   Except for some types of files on external storage, all these options are intended for app-private data—the data is not naturally accessible to other apps.

The last line indicates that most files saved on all these options are app-private except for some types of files on external storage - my understanding is the exception refer to files saved on directories accessed through `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()`.

but again the document declares all files shared on external storage as world-readable :

> Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer.

then it again mention that app-private files can be saved to external storage:

> You can also save files to the external storage in an app-specific directory that the system deletes when the user uninstalls your app. This might be a useful alternative to internal storage if you need more space, but the files here aren't guaranteed to be accessible because the user might remove the storage SD card. And the files are still world readable; they're just saved to a location that's not shared with other apps.

this last paragraph explained things a little bit, but if someone can elaborate and also explain how world-readable files can be private?

Answer (score 0):

> Files saved to the external storage are world-readable and can be modified by the user when they enable USB mass storage to transfer files on a computer.

For example: there's a folder XYZ, it can be accessed by anyone, any App...

> You can also save files to the external storage in an **app-specific directory** that the system deletes when the user uninstalls your app.

Here, your app specific file which might be stored in app specific directories, like **ExternalCacheDirs** (Android/data/com.package.name)

These files are not accessible by other apps...